# Not showing the error message

Tags: php, html

Please read the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>PHP CORRECT CODE</title>
<style type="text/css">
.error{
    position:absolute;
    color:#FF0000;

}
</style>
<?php
$nameErr = $emailErr = $mobileErr = $cityErr = "";
$name = $email = $mobile = $city = "";

if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
    {
        //check name
        if(empty($_REQUEST['name']))
        {
            $nameErr = "Name can not be empty";
        }
        else
        {
            $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        }
        //check email
        if(empty($_REQUEST['email']))
        {
            $emailErr = "Emails can not be empty";
        }
        else
        {
            $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        }
        //check mobile
        if(empty($_REQUEST['mobile']))
        {
            $mobileErr = "Mobile number can not be empty";
        }
        else
        {
            $mobile = $_REQUEST['mobile'];
        }
        //check city
        if(empty($_REQUEST['city']) or $_REQUEST['city']=="")
        {
            $cityErr = "Please select your city";
        }
        else
        {
            $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
        }
}
else
{
    echo "<script>alert('Aplogies we can not proceed this time. Thier is some issues in the form submission. Please refresh the page or try after some time.')</script>";
}
}
?>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<center>
    <h1>CORRECT FORM INSERTION WITH VALIDATION</h1>
    <form name="correct-form" method="GET" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" >
        NAME : <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>" /><span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
        <br/><br/>
        EMAIL : <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>" /><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
        <br/><br/>
        MOBILE : <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($mobile); ?>" /><span class="error"><?php echo $mobileErr; ?></span>
        <br/><br/>
        CITY : <select name="city" id="city" required="required"><span class="error"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($cityErr); ?></span>
                    <option selected="selected" value=""> --Select-- </option>
                    <option value="Jodhpur">JODHPUR</option>
                    <option value="Pali">PALI</option>
                    <option value="Jaipur">JAIPUR</option>
                    <option value="Udaipur">UDAIPUR</option>    
                </select>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="RESET" />
    </form> 
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have done the complete coding for the mandatory fields checking but the last city field making problem for me it's not showing the error message against this as per other fields are showing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have missed this:     if(empty($_REQUEST['city']) or empty($_REQUEST['city']=="")).  After doing this change it's Working As you expected.

Comment: @the-run Why do you have to use `empty()` to determine whether a **boolean** value is true??

Comment: i think you just shot yourself in the foot...the error can't display because you set the field to be required, so the user cannot submit the form without it being empty, the browser will also request for that field to be filled before the form can be submitted

Comment: also take the span out of the select tag so it will display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer with my mind I was just showing the error message before completely ending of the  tag. Now the correct code is.

```
CITY : <select name="city" id="city" required="required">
                    <option selected="selected" value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="Jodhpur">JODHPUR</option>
                    <option value="Pali">PALI</option>
                    <option value="Jaipur">JAIPUR</option>
                    <option value="Udaipur">UDAIPUR</option>    
                </select><span class="error"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($cityErr); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error *is* there:

```
CITY : <select name="city" id="city" required="required"><span class="error">Please select your city</span>
    <option selected="selected" value=""> --Select-- </option>
    <option value="Jodhpur">JODHPUR</option>
    <option value="Pali">PALI</option>
    <option value="Jaipur">JAIPUR</option>
    <option value="Udaipur">UDAIPUR</option>    
    </select>
```

But the browser won't render it. You cannot insert arbitrary contents inside a `<select>` control.